# Compressing files program

Tags: c, algorithm, compression, binary-tree, huffman-code

I'm trying to build a program for compressing files.
I'm using Huffman algorithm and I studied it with the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dM6us854Jk0&t=436s

I tried to use the same way on bits - for start I tried it on Nibbles:
I took each Nibble (16 option) and gave it a random frequency, later I builded a binary tree sorted by the frequencies of the Nibbles just like in the video.

I succeeded to compress 22K of bits into 18K, so far it worked.
Then I tried it on Bytes (256 option) and it didn't work - in the beginning it had 13M bits and after the compress it got 89M.

I have a picture that presents the binary tree of the Nibble example:

[image: img]

and also have two exel files that specify the calculating of the Nibbles tree and Bytes tree:

- Nibbles: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X2clucNxr51li61ASdTVdeZHRtISMS4x/view
- Bytes: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hn0sSRAaNoSzxgbaBzFejtCnaO_9M4Kv/view

I implemented the algorithm with C language and here parts of the functions:

```
typedef struct INFO
{
    unsigned char binary;   //Binary number
    int amount; //Frequency
} INFO;

typedef struct TREE
{
    INFO info;
    struct TREE *prev;
    struct TREE *left;
    struct TREE *right;
} TREE;



/** Function that allocates memory and creates a tree node and initializes it */
TREE * treeNodeMalloc()
{
    TREE *p;
    p = (TREE *)malloc(sizeof(TREE));
    if (!p)
        return NULL;
    p->prev = p->left = p->right = NULL;
    return p;
}


/** Function that builds the first sub-root node consist of two binary numbers */
TREE * firstNode(INFO first, INFO second)
{
    TREE *head, *p;
    int i;
    head = treeNodeMalloc();
    if (!head) return 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        p = treeNodeMalloc();
        if (!p) { freeTree(head); return 0; }
        p->prev = head;
        if (i % 2)
        {
            p->info.amount = first.amount;
            p->info.binary = first.binary;
            head->left = p;
        }
        else
        {
            p->info.amount = second.amount;
            p->info.binary = second.binary;
            head->right = p;
        }
    }
    head->info.amount = head->left->info.amount + head->right->info.amount;
    return head;
}


/** Function that builds a sub-root node that consist of a node of binary number and a sub-root of two previous binary numbers */
TREE * continuanceNode(TREE *p1, INFO info)
{
    TREE *h, *p2;
    h = treeNodeMalloc();
    if (!h) { freeTree(p1); return 0; }
    p2 = treeNodeMalloc();
    if (!p2) { free(h); freeTree(p1); return 0; }
    p2->info.amount = info.amount;
    p2->info.binary = info.binary;
    p1->prev = p2->prev = h;
    h->left = p1;
    h->right = p2;
    h->info.amount = h->left->info.amount + h->right->info.amount;
    return h;
}


/** Function that builds the last node of the tree - the main root */
TREE * LastNode(TREE *p1, TREE *p2)
{
    TREE *p3;
    p3 = treeNodeMalloc();
    if (!p3)
    {
        freeTree(p1);
        freeTree(p2);
        return NULL;
    }
    p3->left = p1;
    p3->right = p2;
    p1->prev = p2->prev = p3;
    p3->info.amount = p3->left->info.amount + p3->right->info.amount;
    return p3;
}



/** Function that builds the binary tree from the array of INFO (binary numbers and their frequencies),
The function builds the tree from bottum to the top (reverse build) */
TREE * dataToTree(INFO arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    TREE *h, *p, *t=NULL;
    p = firstNode(arr[0], arr[1]);
    if (!p) return 0;
    for (i = 2; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (p->info.amount > arr[size - 1].amount)
            if (!t)
            {
                t = firstNode(arr[i], arr[i + 1]); 
                i++;
                if (!t) { freeTree(p); return NULL; }
            }
            else
                if (p->info.amount < t->info.amount)
                {
                    p = continuanceNode(p, arr[i]);
                    if (!p) { freeTree(t); return 0; }
                }
                else
                {
                    t = continuanceNode(t, arr[i]);
                    if (!t) { freeTree(p); return 0; }
                }
        else
        {
            p = continuanceNode(p, arr[i]);
            if (!p) { freeTree(t); return 0; }
        }
    }
    h = LastNode(p, t);
    return h;
}
```

Everyone says Huffman algorithm is the best for compressing files so what am I missing here?
what am I doing worng?

Comment: Please see if you can reduce your code to a minimal length - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I'm a afraid it already minimal - the full code is very long and I added only the relevant functions and structures. The code works exactly the way I want and implementes the algorithm as I "see" it, I just thought maybe you'll ask for it. I think the problem is about the way I use the algorithm on bits, (How I "see" it)

Comment: `Everyone says Huffman algorithm is the best for compressing files` Who and in which context? Have a look at [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).

Comment: I yet got to the complexity of the algorithm, for now I try to implemente it, if you're asking who told me to use it, well I've done a research about that when I needed to look for the best and comfortable algorithm for compressing file, and found that algorithm as suitable.

Answer (score 1):

The Huffman tree you constructed is wrong. At each step you need to **fuse the two nodes with the lowest frequencies** among all available root nodes. So first fuse 9 and 14 which gives you:

```
  21
 /  \
9   14
```

Next step is to fuse 21 and 20

```
    41
   /  \
  21  20
 /  \
9   14
```

Then 41 and 50

```
      91
     /  \
    41  50
   /  \
  21  20
 /  \
9   14
```

But at this step the two lowest are 70 and 80, so fuse them separately

```
      91     150
     /  \   /  \
    41  50 70  80
   /  \
  21  20
 /  \
9   14
```

Then after you have to fuse the two lowest, 91 and 100, etc.

The tree will then be more "equilibrated", and the result **may be** better.

You should know (from coding theory) that some texts cannot be compressed. For a given compressing algorithm there always exists at least one text that cannot be compressed. And in general whatever any algorithm you try to use, there exists at least one text that cannot be compressed. All of these need some more theoretical explanation but it is roughly what theory can say.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to rebuild the tree according to your construct and come back with the results.

Comment: I'm sorry but I feel like I'm getting lost at the algorithm steps, I'm not sure how to continue from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RVJoumOydsiiE5zI-qdc42FOgHOR9nEL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Build a list of nodes, sort them by weight, fuse both of lowest weight replace both by the root in the list, sort the list (a simple insertion will be sufficient), and then continue until list is reduced to a single root node.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.